# Throttling - Maximum method calls per second

Tags: c#, wcf, throttling

I am consuming a web service via WCF and I want to restrict service method calls by N every second. Is there a class that will help me achieve this. Or do I need to manually update a count and reset it every second.

Comment: You want to throttle in the client, at the server, or both? Much of the overhead in using WCF web services is in serializing and making the call. Just something to be aware of if you're doing this to improve performance.

Comment: Are you writing the WCF service that consumes the web service, or just accessing the web service via WCF? If you're rolling the service, you may be able to effectively throttle calls to the web service by setting the throttling settings on your WCF service. If you're just consuming the web service, I think you might be stuck writing your own counter mechanism.

Comment: What are you trying to prevent with this kind of throttle - are you consuming some resource which has a timed throttle or charging model itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a helpful article on throttling

http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/02/20/how-to-throttle-a-wcf-service-help-prevent-dos-attacks-and-maintain-wcf-scalability/

You can use the built in throttling methods in code:

```
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(
typeof(MyContract),
new Uri("http://localhost:8080/MyContract"));
host.AddServiceEndpoint("IMyContract", new WSHttpBinding(), "");
System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceThrottlingBehavior throttlingBehavior =
new System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceThrottlingBehavior();
throttlingBehavior.MaxConcurrentCalls = 16;
throttlingBehavior.MaxConcurrentInstances = Int32.MaxValue;
throttlingBehavior.MaxConcurrentSessions = 10;
host.Description.Behaviors.Add(throttlingBehavior);
host.Open();
```

or put them into the web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
    <service
        name="IMyContract"
        behaviorConfiguration="myContract">
        <host>
            <baseAddresses>
                <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/MyContract"/>
            </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint
            name="wsHttp"
            address=""
            binding="wsHttpBinding"
            contract="IMyContract">
        </endpoint>
    </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="myContract">
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" />
            <serviceThrottling
                maxConcurrentCalls="16"
                maxConcurrentInstances="2147483647"
                maxConcurrentSessions="10"/>
        </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```